# JqueryUI (Ajax) Hide() works, Show() does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm very new to JQuery/Ajax and I haven't done any HTML for a long time, so please do forgive me if this is a dumb question.  I've done a fair amount of reading, and I'm at a loss.

In a nutshell, on completion of a `FlipClock.js` countdown timer, the clock should slide off the page to the right, which works.  However, on starting the timer, I'd like the div to slide onto the page from the right, but I cannot get the div to move.  Here's my code:

```
function showTimer() {
$(".clock").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 2000); //Does nothing, seemingly
timerRunning= true;
var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(3, {
    countdown: true,
    clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
    callbacks: {
        stop: function() {
            timerStopped();
        }
    }

});
}

function timerStopped() {
        console.log("Test function on clock stop!");
        $('.clock').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);

        }
```

I've not set up any CSS for the `clock` div, so I'm not sure if I need to position it off screen to begin with, but hide works, so I'm a little confused.

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling showTimer() somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, sorry, there's a switch statement higher up that calls it.  Only called from one place, and only called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of debugging, I have found a solution. Please try it out in jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mLkfyrd8/1/

Things that may have gone wrong:

1. Forgot to wrap in $(document).ready()
2. Forgot to include jQuery/jQuery UI library
3. Forgot to call $(".clock").hide()

UPDATE: There seems to be an issue with the clock moving up/down. See [this new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2h9kk9g/) for the fixed version (added padding.)

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".container").hide();

    function showTimer() {

        $('.clock').FlipClock(3, {
            countdown: true,
            clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
            callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                    timerStopped();
                }
            }

        });

        $(".container").show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 2000);

    }


    function timerStopped() {
        console.log("Test function on clock stop!");
        $('.container').hide('slide',{direction:'right'},1000);
    }

    showTimer();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/master/compiled/flipclock.css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/master/compiled/flipclock.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" style="padding: 20px;"><div class="clock"></div></div>
```

Comment: Aha, seems I didn't call hide before calling show!!  That explains it.  Thanks very for your help!!

Comment: One thing I have noticed, when sliding the div in and out, it moves up a fraction, it's only slight, but it's a little annoying.  Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: @Tony Yes, I am noticing that too. :)

Comment: @Tony It only does that when you make the div a FlipClock. If you don't, it doesn't happen. Eg. https://jsfiddle.net/6aeq0krf/ the div doesn't move up/down. Maybe you can try to wrap the clock div in another div and animate the container instead? Eg. `<div class="container"><div class="clock"></div></div>` and animate `.container` and not `.clock`?

Comment: <div class="clockContainer">
   <div class="clock"><script src="flipclock.min.js"></script></div>
  </div>

Comment: It's still moving up and down :(

Comment: @Tony Fixed it! Just added a bit of padding to the clockContainer. Will update my answer shortly...

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Nathan, that was driving me crazy :)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should set dimensions and position to your clock div. Look it up with e.g. firebug (hit F12) and search your clock div. There you should see where the div is and it might be outside of your viewport. And do you get the console log output?

Comment: At the moment the clock is appearing at the very top left of the page.  I'll try using a fixed position on it.  Thanks.

Comment: try to give `position:absolute;` and `top:300px;` `left:300px;` `width:100px;` `height:100px;` . Now you should see your clock and in whiich direction it's toggled.

Comment: The clock is now appearing half way down the page, but it's just appearing on refresh, it's not sliding.  None of the other effects seem to work, such as explode, for example.

Comment: It's currently being called like this:  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
       
         console.log("Starting timer");
         showTimer();
       
        }

Comment: It looks like you are using jquery? You pass the wrong arguments to the show method. It could be `.show( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )` or `.show( options )` or `.show( [duration ] [, complete ] )` or `show()`. See http://api.jquery.com/show/. Try the show call without any arguments and see if it appears.

Comment: Thanks Ben, turns out I was doing it wrong (as per usual), I wasn't calling hide before show!  Thanks for your help though